# Port Codeigniter App to PyroCMS

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system, pyrocms

I'm working on a web application in Codeigniter. I'd like to integrate the functionality of my application with a CMS so that site admins can easily update the site (about pages, blog, etc). Is this easily done with PyroCMS or another Codeigniter-based CMS? Will I need to drastically restructure my existing app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my own experience integrating an app inside Expression Engine I can say that a CMS changes the way you usually work with CI. So be prepared to make some adjustments. Every CMS will come with it's perks and differences. It shouldn't be a big problem though.

If you want to use PyroCms take a look at this doc first:
http://www.pyrocms.com/docs/2.0/developers/creating-custom-modules

If you're looking for alternatives, there are a lot. It seems almost everyone working with CI has made it's own.

Here are a few:

- http://www.ionizecms.com/
- http://www.halogy.com/
- http://codefight.org/
- http://www.getfuelcms.com/

Also make sure you check out CI Bonfire, it's not a CMS but does help you when you start up a new project with a basic admin wrapper, which is sometimes more useful than a CMS:

http://cibonfire.com/

Comment: Thanks for that link to CI BonFire.. can't tell you how many times i've had the need for something like that.

Comment: :) I wish there were more apps like this. Way too often you start projects with a bloated CMS while a simpler admin wrapper like Bonfire would do.

Comment: Thanks for the roundup of Codeigniter cms's  - I went with FuelCMS. I'm pretty stoked on it's Opt-in Controller wrapper that passes variables directly to views, somewhat reminiscent of Drupal's preprocess functions. I also like the way FuelCMS builds a CRUD interface from the database table with the help of a simple Model class... I ended up just mirroring my app's database structure using fuelcms's controllers... so far so good.

Answer (score 4):

This was answered a year ago and answered well, but my support guy has forwarded me a few emails from users asking about this page.

When people talk about Content Management Systems they often suddenly get the idea of rigid backends where you applications have to follow specific rules. While PyroCMS certainly has a few conventions you are free to build your modules just like they are a CodeIgniter application, on the frontend or the backend.

If you want to use Models, Controllers, Views, REST API's, SOAP, whatever the hell, then you can do that.

But, we also offer some awesome tools to make building modules CRAZY-fast. Hate writing CRUD? Well don't bother. Using the [Streams API](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/index.php/developers/tools/streams-api/index) you can leverage the build in "Custom Data" system we use to rock out chunks of interface for you.

Using PyroCMS for your application is certainly not "hacking it into a CMS", this is the exact use-case it was built for.

If you have an existing application, while you can't "put PyroCMS into your app" you can certainly convert your application to a [module](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/index.php/developers/addons/modules/basic-structure) easy enough.

Comment: I am not really advising against it though :), just providing options as asked for. Not every app is the same. I had no idea I was stopping people from using PyroCMS, which is a solid system! I might refine my answer to be more precise and clear.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing it is to write your models around the CMS' database. Host the CMS at a subdomain with authentication for your admins. (admin.mysite.com) or something and then use the same database to power your front-end for your site.

- **Is it the best approach?** Probably not.
- **Will it work?** Yes.

You will probably find it hard to expand vertically & add new features if you're relying on a 3rd party CMS for data entry & backend.