# Add CMS subsystem to Codeigniter site

Tags: codeigniter, content-management-system

I have a rather complex (one man year development in total) specialist website application based on a CodeIgniter framework.  I now have a requirement to add CMS functionality to it so that the users can add articles and similar content to the system to compliment the main functionality.

There are obviously several CodeIgniter CMS systems available - [FuelCMS](http://www.getfuelcms.com/)  and [PyroCMS](http://www.pyrocms.com) for example, but which of these (or another) would be best for integrating into a developed  site with minimal impact on existing code?

Comment: If you have done the complete website in CodeIgniter, I would suggest to implement the article module in the developed website rather than integrating with another CMS. Because user management and etc have to be changed in your developed website or in the CMS code.

Comment: Agree with @Nish, modularize your code https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you have already. Do you have RBAC in place? If so, that's already half the battle.
There's a lot out there but integrating those might turn out to be more work then writing your own system.

I've answered a similar question a while ago, about merging existing CI projects with a CMS, it might give you some more insight:
[Port Codeigniter App to PyroCMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459206/port-codeigniter-app-to-pyrocms/9181365#9181365)